# how to make a Pawn not to dettected by PawnSensing in Unreal 5 engine?

Tags: unreal-engine5

i have a Bot that shooting on me when it senses me with PawnSensing.
after i die (in Radgoll status) the Bot is countinuing shooting on me.
Is there any way that the dead player will stop been dettected by the PawnSensing?

I was expecting to find some property that make me not been dettected.